# Self-publishing options for a card came with box

Tags: playing-cards, game-development

I would like to self-publish my card game with a service that will ship the game to buyers.

The game would include 45 poker-size cards, 17 A5-size cards, 6 small cards carrying 1-6 numbers (as a replacement for a die), a game instructions sheet and a box.

I know two services:

- TGC but I read they are expensive and not high quality for cards.
- DriveThru Cards seems to be great but I believe they don't do boxes, am I right?

Are there any other services which could do this for me?

Comment: Where are you publishing this game? And do you plan to deliver to the domestic market only, or also internationally?

Comment: I live in Europe, but my main target would be the US, so I would be publishing there. If I can find a good solution for this, I would already be happy. However, it is true that I would like to target Europe as well.

Comment: Do you think I could have these cards shipped to buyers without a game box? I guess DriveThru would make a parcel including the cards in their three different sizes. That would be a bit strange, or do you think it would be ok?

Comment: No, I'd definitely go for boxed. How many unboxed - non-prototype- games do you have in your games cupboard?

Comment: Indeed. So any service that could do this for me? In the States or in Europe?

Comment: It is true that it would not make sense to send a game consisting of cards in three different sizes without a box. I am now thinking that I could make all cards in A5 format. They are not cards that you need to keep in your hand, only briefly refer to them and then do some actions. So if I use DriveThru and make one A5 card with the cover of the game and the instructions on the other side, plus 68 A5 cards to play and no box, do you think that could work out fine?

Comment: Still tricky without a tuckbox (which they won't do for individual sales) or a plastic deck box, which they won't do for bigger formats than bridge or poker cards. Any other ideas or alternative self-publishing providers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about designing the game or testing game mechanics, but  soliciting recommendations for production services.

Answer (score 1):

DriveThruCards now offers tuck boxes.

Daniel Solis gives a great review of them [here](http://danielsolisblog.blogspot.com/2016/10/new-tuck-boxes-from-drivethrucards.html).

Comment: The information that DTC offers boxes is definitely useful, but its usefulness is masked by the "have you tried" question which makes it look like you didn't read OP who explicitly mentions DTC. Perhaps rephrase?

Comment: I've fixed my answer, and added a link to a review of said tuck boxes from DTC.